# Kotlin compilation error: unresolved AspectJ supertype

Tags: interop, aspectj, kotlin

I'm trying to use a Java library in my Kotlin project.

Creating variables in my project of types defined in the library works fine, e.g. `val foo: Foo = fooProvider.get()`, but introducing code that actually *uses* these types, e.g. `foo.toString()`, causes a compilation error:

```
Error:Kotlin: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.example.Foo, unresolved supertypes: ajcMightHaveAspect
```

From what I have found so far my example `Foo` type `implements` `ajcMightHaveAspect` which is some type of AspectJ interface.

`aspectjrt` is on my classpath but I cannot find `ajcMightHaveAspect` defined anywhere.

Is this a Kotlin compiler bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12179 with a demo project attached which reproduces the compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed in `AspectJ`.

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493554 for more details .

Hope it will help.